# extract "wrapped" values from a string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as below:

```
randomword,random${notavalue;randomword${iwantthisrandompart1}randomword${iwantthisrandompart2}randomword
```

How can I extract only the values inside the `${}`, namely `iwantthisrandompart1` and `iwantthisrandompart2` in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s="randomword,random${notavalue;randomword${iwantthisrandompart1}randomword${iwantthisrandompart2}randomword"
var myRe=/\$\{([^}{]*)\}/g
var m=myRe.exec(s)
while (m!=null) {alert(m[1]);m=myRe.exec(s)}
```

give this a try. the part you need will be "alerted"

Answer (score -1):

this will solve your troubles

```
(?<=\$\{)[^\$\{]*(?=\})
```

regex demo here : http://regex101.com/r/oY0bU9

**update : since javascript doesnt support lookbehind**

```
(?=\$\{)\$\{([^\$\{]*(?=\}))
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/rJ3nI3

Comment: javascript supports look around?

Comment: ohh i didnt see that tag Kent, nyways this will work for other languages and yes javascript supports lookahead, it just doesnt support lookbehind.

Comment: `(?=\$\{)\$\{` The lookahead is useless here.